# MAUI Android Scroll to new view without tabs

Tags: android, maui

I'm building a home app for an Android device. What is the best way to replicate the experience on a typical mobile, I.e. have a home screen that displays the time and search box etc. Then when scrolling it opens a list of available apps.

[Scrolling can either be vertical or horizontal, whichever solution is most viable]

I have tried with a TabbedPage. The problem with this, I haven't worked out how to remove the tabs. It should only be navigable via scrolling not clicking the tab.

[image]

The CarouselView only supports adding an ItemsTemplate which doesn't make sense here as I need different content on the home screen verses the apps list.

What is my best way forwards?

Comment: If you don't want tabs, perhaps use NavigationPage instead of TabbedPage.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve can I still use scrolling to go to the next page? And will I be able to do this with slow scroll too much like when you slowly scroll on tabs it shows half of each page?

Comment: Probably you can swipe to next page, by writing your own code that runs when there is a swipe gesture. But I don't think that would show the incoming page. See [swipe gesture doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/swipe). I have not tried this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CollectionView` to achieve this. More information you can refer to [Configure CollectionView item selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/selection).

First, you can use the CollectionView to show the data and use the `SelectionChangedCommand` to choose the item which you want.

Second, you can write a navigation code for the SelectedItem. You can refer to [.NET MAUI Shell navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation).

Comment: How does this solve my problem? You can only set the source to a collection. Not pages.
Additionally, it wouldn't allow for scrolling that snaps to the page.

Comment: You can bind the navigation command to the CollectionViewItem. When you click the item in the collectionview you can navigate to the target page.

Comment: You've missed the whole point of the question! This is specifically about scrolling to a new page without clicking on ANY element. Your answer doesn't do this.

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake. For this situation, it is recommended to use the [swipe gesture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/swipe).